# Shortest s-t path when is allowed to ignore k weights

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms

Given an undirected graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, with non-negative weights on the edges, what's the best algorithm that computes the shortest path from $s$ to $t$, where you are allowed to ignore the weight (i.e. set to $0$) of at most $k$ edges on the path?

An $O(kn\log(kn)+km)$ homework-level solution will be copy the graph $k$ times and use dijkstra. But is there any better algorithm (or lower bound)?